# JMeter response times much larger than the requests' latencies

Tags: caching, jmeter, response-time

JMeter machines with versions: 2.13 r13365067, 2.11.20140918 |
Java: OpenJDK 1.7.0_79 | 
OS: Debian 8.1

I'm having a problem where some HTTP requests seem to be processed far too long on a load injector that isn't really under load.

Examples from result files from tests with 20 vUs (with caching, on weaker load injector, JMeter v2.11) and 40vUs (without caching, on much higher spec'd load injector, JMeter v2.13):

```
<time_stamp>,3257,<request_name>,200,<thread_name>,true,28537,20,20,437
<time_stamp>,5158,<request_name>,304,<thread_name>,true,138,40,40,0
```

Memory is at 75% in the first case, and below 50% in the second. CPU doesn't seem to spike (measured in 1 sec intervals) and goes up to 20% max in both examples.
Checked the JVM's garbage collection, and it doesn't seem like the GC is at its limits at the time of the requests either (actually at no point during the test).

I noticed this in the case where I had caching (via Cache Manager with "Use Cache-Control/Expires headers..." checked) enabled, and, like in the second example above, get the unrealistic response time of 5158 ms.

This only happens at some steps during an iteration and to more than one thread, but not all.

It seems like JMeter is somehow processing the result too long, but I can't really see that my load injectors are under heavy load, to cause processing times of seconds.

Clearly this is messing up the performance statistics so I would like to know how this is happening.

Hope someone can help.

EDIT:
@First example: Case where ResponseTime >> Latecy > 0, happens on both JMeter machines (JMeter v2.11, JMeter v2.13).

@Second example: Case where ResponseTime >> Latecy = 0 happens *only* on the machine with JMeter v2.13.

---

2nd EDIT:
Turns out it doesn't matter what JMeter version I run (or on which node).

Regex'd my result file:
Of the same requested resources, cached (latency=0), with header check, about 10% took 1 second or multiple seconds. Without header check it is 6%.

Answer (score 1):

You should run same JMeter version on all nodes. If this won't solve the problem, monitor your JMeter instance resource utilisation with jconsole.

Comment: I'm using VisualVM actually. Looked at the monitor during a test, captured CPU profiling. I compared the time stamps of the suspicious sampler results to the GC activity, but I'm not sure I can make out a pattern.

Comment: Can you see peak CPU usage?

Comment: There are CPU spikes occuring in the time intervals of the response times. Some suspicious samples are processed when GCs are taking place (spikes in the heap), but not exclusively during those. What other metrics could be useful here to dig deeper?

Comment: CPU is frequently maxed out during JMeter execution when there is no more memory available. Can you try to increase xmx/xms JVM params and see if you still have the same problem?

Comment: BTW, I hope you don't run the test in GUI mode with listeners enabled? (especially view results tree and similar)

Comment: #CPU: My nodes' CPU actually never goes beyond 50%, and it's almost always below 10%. In fact, at the time where I got a bunch (17 out of 40) threads experiencing a high response, the CPU curve is below 4%, the request finishes on a slope to a small CPU spike. I assume that spike belongs to another request. #JVM parameter: Increased min and max heap from 512->2048. No effect. #GUI mode: Ofc I'm running in -n mode -- ever since I found out it exists...and after my very first load tests produced response time and throughput graphs that looked wrong. Only listener on is Console listener JM-plugin

Comment: Also took a look at VisualVM's snapshot, but the particular threads are not spending any extra time in any method, that the other threads, which did not experience high response time, don't spend in--only time spent is in JMeterThread.process_sampler, JMeterThread.delay (constant timer), TestAction.sample (test action timer I use at the end of a loop). The latter I tried deactivating already, but that didn't help. It's strange. It's almost as if JMeter is simulating some kind of expensive response message parsing out of the cache.